# Java LibGdx 2d terrain generator

Tags: java, libgdx, generator, perlin-noise

Hello I try to do game like terraria but I don't have idea how to generate random terrain :(. Someone can help me ?. I search in internet but I don't find anything, only some thing with perlin noise. And sorry from my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'answer' for such a complex problem. It takes a lot of time to develop a program to create such a terrain generator. If you really want to make it, you should research Diamond-square, Simplex Noise and Perlin Noise algorithms (although it's university grade stuff).

The terraria generator is most likely comprised of a series of complex algorithms, e.g.: one to generate a rough hill type terrain, then to generate caves, create dungeons, etc.

If you expect someone to just post you some code, I'm afraid that won't be possible. It will require a lot of programming which you'll have to complete yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon what kind of terrain you want to generate, an algorithm such as the [Diamond-square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm) will generate realistic seeming ground surfaces.

Comment: I wont to generate world like terraria with caves etc.